# Is there a way to make the Quick Find dialog wait until you hit enter to find results in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I'm trying to search for something in the current document, I think it's really annoying that VS immediately starts trying to find a match when I've only typed a single character. The document ends up jumping all over the place, causing me to lose my spot. Is there any way to make it so VS doesn't start looking for results until I actually hit enter?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the find and replace dialog instead of quick find. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or 
 Edit > Find And Replace > Find in Files.  Then just switch the dropdown to `current document`.  Although this creates a list that you can click through rather than navigating directly.

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I'm looking for though. That would just introduce a new annoyance of having to constantly change what I'm trying to search for in the Find in Files dialog.